# Embedding Sharepoint Web Part in Java Script

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, web-parts, zone

I've deployed a sharepoint web page and added a custom webpart that visualized data the way customers want to see it. The problem with the webpart is that we cannot scale, modify, or hide it when the user wants to. We thought to embed the Sharepoint webpart in a Java wrapper. Typically this would be easy on a standard HTML page. The question is how do I embed a webpart inside a java wrapper in Sharepoint?

I want to add 2 html buttons, one to show the webpart and one to hide the webpart. The challenge is finding the webpart ID that I can pass to either button to execute the hideMe or showMe java script.

The webpart header:

```
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" Title="loc:FullPage" ID="FullPage" FrameType="TitleBarOnly"><ZoneTemplate>
<WpNs0:Trend runat="server" __MarkupType="xmlmarkup" WebPart="true" __WebPartId="{AFA8DE0A-E7B4-4580-BFAB-038D96E72F0A}" >
```

The code (so far)

```
<button onclick="HideWebpart('AFA8DE0A-E7B4-4580-BFAB-038D96E72F0A')">Hide Me</button>
<button onclick="ShowWebpart('AFA8DE0A-E7B4-4580-BFAB-038D96E72F0A')">Show Me</button>

<script>
function HideWebpart(AFA8DE0A-E7B4-4580-BFAB-038D96E72F0A)
{
    var wp=document.getElementById(AFA8DE0A-E7B4-4580-BFAB-038D96E72F0A);
    wp.className = "hidden";
}

function ShowWebpart(AFA8DE0A-E7B4-4580-BFAB-038D96E72F0A)
{
    var wp=document.getElementById(AFA8DE0A-E7B4-4580-BFAB-038D96E72F0A);
    wp.className = "";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so you can give the WebPart an id="mywebpart", then simply use a JavaScript function to hide it.

Example:

```
<style type="text/css>
    .hidden { display:none; }
</style>
<script>
function HideWebpart(id_of_webpart)
{
    var wp=document.getElementById(id_of_webpart);
    wp.className = "hidden";
}

function ShowWebpart(id_of_webpart)
{
    var wp=document.getElementById(id_of_webpart);
    wp.className = "";
}
</script>
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
..The SVG WebPart... <--Add WebPart with id here
</WebPartPages:WebpartZone>

<button onclick="HideWebpart('PASS WEB PART ID IN HERE')"/>
```

---

I believe the problem is you want to use the "__WebPartId=" attribute when getElementById will only look for the "id=" attribute. so go find an element by a custom attribute you will need to use the following instead of getElementById:

```
function getElementByAttribute(attr, value, root) {
    root = root || document.body;
    if(root.hasAttribute(attr) && root.getAttribute(attr) == value) {
        return root;
    }
    var children = root.children, 
        element;
    for(var i = children.length; i--; ) {
        element = getElementByAttribute(attr, value, children[i]);
        if(element) {
            return element;
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
getElementByAttribute("__WebPartId",'PASS WEB PART ID IN HERE');
```

Note: It will be much slower compared to getElementById because you cannot make use of any index

Or if you can use the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) library you can use simply $('[__WebPartId="PASS WEB PART ID IN HERE"]')

Comment: almost but you leave the function as a variable. For example function HideWebpart(id_variable) { var wp=document.getElementById(id_variable); wp.className = "hidden"; }

Comment: Ok..Elliot, the funny part is that I orginally asked how to get the webpart to show and to hide through code. The answer you gave me was incomplete without the ability to hide or show the webpart through user interaction. (i.e no buttons or links) I gave you credit because you asked me too.  Let's try this again and bear with me. My question again is how do I parameterize the webpart ID (presumably __WebPartId="{AFA8DE0A-E7B4-4580-BFAB-038D96E72F0A}" so that my "hide" and/or "show" button actually interact with the webpart in Sharepoint

Comment: lol sorry you miss understand, I am very happy to help. I meant If you update your original question with what you have so far I can edit my answer to give you some better code snippets then trying to cram code into this little comment box.

Comment: Figured it out... Ok so I "encase" for lack of a better word my webpart inside a <div> and give it an id <div class="myWebPart1"> then in my js call that <div> id into play.. in my js scripted at the top of the .aspx right between </style> and </asp:Content>. It actually works better for me this way, in that I can go crazy with one or more webparts having them all wrapped in <div>s I can call at will from the top. I can use Sharepoint designer to mask the ugliness of the webpart further. Thanks for at least giving me the idea! /cheer